# Populating a data frame using from separate table using loc

Tags: python, pandas

```
data1={'Policy Number':['FSH1235456','FSH7643643','CHH123124','CHH123145252','CHH124124'],'State':['FL','TX','GA','TX','TX'],'TERR':[1,2,3,4,5]}

data2={'TERR':[1,2,3,4,5],'CHH':[0,.15,.65,.35,.20],'FSH':[0,.15,.25,.35,.20]}

output={'Policy Number':['FSH1235456','FSH7643643','CHH123124','CHH123145252','CHH124124'],'State':['FL','TX','GA','TX','TX'],'TERR':[1,2,3,4,5],'Test':[0,.15,0,0,0]}


df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)

df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)

df3=pd.DataFrame(output)
```

Test data above.

I am trying to create a new column in df1 call it df1['Test'], which contains the values of df2['FSH'] based on the following criteria:

1. The state is 'TX'
2. The Policy Number contains 'FSH' 
   3.The value of df1["Terr"] = value of df2['TERR']

View df3 for correct output.

What I tried doing was the following;

```
if df1.State.any()=="TX":
    if df1["Policy Number"].str.contains("FSH").any():
        for i in df["TERR"]:
            df1['% TERR']=df2.loc[[i],["FSH"]]
```

However, my output is riddled with NAN, as well as 1 unique correct answer.

I tried checking to ensure the correct i values were being fed into df2 via

```
print(df2.loc[[i],["FSH"]]
```

and it is printing correctly.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is the best or fastest solution but one option is to merge your 2 dataframes then filter based on your conditions then update:

```
new = df1.merge(df2, on='TERR')
mask = new[((new['State']=='TX') & (new['Policy Number'].str.contains('FSH')))]

df1['Test'] = 0
df1['Test'].update(mask['FSH'])

    Policy Number   State   TERR    Test
0   FSH1235456        FL    1       0.00
1   FSH7643643        TX    2       0.15
2   CHH123124         GA    3       0.00
3   CHH123145252      TX    4       0.00
4   CHH124124         TX    5       0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy where by passing conditions,

```
cond1 = (df1['State'] == 'TX')
cond2 = (df1['Policy Number'].str.contains('FSH'))
cond3 = (df1["TERR"] == df2['TERR'])
df1['Test'] = np.where(cond1 & cond2 & cond3, df2['FSH'], 0)

    Policy Number   State   TERR    Test
0   FSH1235456      FL      1       0.00
1   FSH7643643      TX      2       0.15
2   CHH123124       GA      3       0.00
3   CHH123145252    TX      4       0.00
4   CHH124124       TX      5       0.00
```

Comment: This is a great solution, however how would you take into consideration the case where the shapes do not match exactly?

Comment: You can use map when the shapes of dataframes do not match but in this case, the mapping is possible only based TERR columns. The other two conditions are still index based

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to get the data from `df2` into `df1`? If so, you could reshape `df2` using `melt` and then do a `merge`.

```
df1['policy_prefix'] = df1['Policy Number'].str[:3]
df2 = df2.melt(id_vars='TERR', value_vars=['CHH', 'FSH'], 
               value_name='Test', 
               var_name='policy_prefix')
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=['policy_prefix', 'TERR'])
```

if you only want this to apply to rows where the state is 'TX' then you could set the other values to null after the merge:

```
   import numpy as np 
   df1.loc[df1.State!='TX', 'Test'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
# ... initialize df1 and df2 here
df3 = df1.join(df2.FSH)  # Merge df1 and df2 into a single dataframe
df3 = df3.rename({"FSH": "TEST"}, axis=1)  # Change column name

def set_tx_fsh(row):
    if row.State == "TX" and "FSH" in row["Policy Number"]:
        return row.TEST
    else:
        return 0

df3.TEST = df3.apply(set_tx_fsh, axis=1)  # Set values in "TEST" column based on your condition
```